# Controls disappear in design mode using visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer, designmode

I'm working in a windows forms project using visual studio 2005 sp1, i've a lot of usercontrol that use for my user interface, yesterday i start to have problem with the designmode, when i open a usercontrol all control disappear, i check the design file and the definition of the controls is still there, when i run the app there is no problem.

I try to use this code inside the Load of every usercontrol

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
   // Put some logic here
}
```

however, the problem persist. Today my usercontrol doesn´t display in designmode but either in runtime.

How can be posible? Any suggestion for that?

Regards,

Francisco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Check the .Designer.cs file again and make sure the controls which disappeared are added to their parent controls. Like

```
 this.pCheck.Controls.Add(this.pCheck_bLog_browse);
```

While checking the differences with previous revisions I figured out that for some reason these lines just disappeared.